# Как найти min , max значение по засданному столбцу?

Tags: python, pandas

Как найти минимальное и максимальное значение по столбцу `Fixed_assets_value`?

Никак не идет:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('zad_p.csv', delimiter=';')
df = df.rename(columns={'fixed assets value': 'Fixed_assets_value', 'gross output  at constant prices': 'Gross_output_at_constant_prices', 'average on establishment number of workers' : 'Average_on_establishment_number_of_workers', 'Average daily processing of beets' : 'Average_daily_processing_of_beets'})
df
df.Fixed_assets_value.max()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в доках листайте вниз, там примеры https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Comment: Что выводит print(df.columns.to_list()) ?

Comment: Ошибки с точки зрения языка и библиотеки pandas в вашем коде нет. Скорее всего, вы просто не выполнили обновленный код в том месте, где переименовываете столбцы, в результате чего нужный вам столбец ещё отсутствует в устаревшем df. Просто перезапустите выполнение всех ячеек.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что столбца с таким наименованием нет в DataFrame.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({"fixed assets value": [1,2,3,], "gross output  at constant prices": [11,12,13]})

In [21]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[21]: ['fixed assets value', 'gross output  at constant prices']

In [22]: df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\s+", "_")

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   fixed_assets_value  gross_output_at_constant_prices
0                   1                               11
1                   2                               12
2                   3                               13
```

теперь попытаемся найти максимум/минимум для существующих и несуществующих столбцов:

```
In [24]: df.fixed_assets_value.max()
Out[24]: 3

In [25]: df.gross_output_at_constant_prices.min()
Out[25]: 11

In [26]: df.non_existing_col.max()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'non_existing_col'
```

PS более идиоматично/правильно обращаться к столбцам фрейма используя квадратные скобки - это будет работать для любых наименований столбцов, даже для таких, которые содержат пробелы или символы пунктуации.

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col 1": [1,2], "col,2;": [10,20]})

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   col 1  col,2;
0      1      10
1      2      20

In [29]: df["col,2;"].mean()
Out[29]: 15.0
```

разумеется обратиться к такому столбцу как к атрибуту не получится:

```
In [30]: df.col,2;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
```

PPS чтобы получить полный список столбцов DataFrame в виде обычного списка:

```
In [31]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[31]: ['col 1', 'col,2;']
```

Answer (score 3):

Если простыми словами, то `pandas.DataFrame` - это структура данных наподобие обычного python-словаря `dict`, просто построенная на библиотеке `numpy` и имеющая больше возможностей. В этом контексте у объектов `pandas.DataFrame` (переменная `df` в вашем случае) возможно получение значения по ключу. Ключом является что-то хэшируемое (`Hashable`), т.е. нечто "уникальное" - например, строка типа `str` является в python хэшируемым объектом.

Так вот это всё к чему... А к тому, что в вашем случае нужно делать так:

```py
df['Fixed_assets_value'].max()
```

`df['Fixed_assets_value']` возвращает содержимое столбца с именем `'Fixed_assets_value'` в виде объекта типа `pandas.Series` (ибо столбцами `pandas.DataFrame` являются объекты типа `pandas.Series`), у которого существует метод поиска максимального значения.

То, что делали вы...

```py
df.Fixed_assets_value.max()
```

...означало, что вы пытались достучаться до поля `Fixed_assets_value` объекта `pandas.DataFrame`. Но такого поля там просто нет.

**P.S.**

Даже если вы совсем-совсем новичок - не бойтесь рыться в документации :) Потратив время сейчас, в будущем вы сэкономите много сил, энергии, здоровья и того же времени). К тому же у `pandas` (как и у многих библиотек python) документация прекрасна.

Comment: если столбец `Fixed_assets_value` существует в DataFrame, то команда `df.Fixed_assets_value.max()` - замечательно отработает ;)